# Using Grep + Regex linux

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I am trying to find the value "PASS_MAX_DAYS" equal to 90 or less in the /etc/login.defs file But it does not work, I am testing on a suse 12 server but the command does not work.

`grep "^PASS_MAX_DAYS\s*([0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|90)" /etc/login.defs`

Thanks for your support and time

Comment: I suggest to use `awk` for this job.

Comment: `grep` is for finding text patterns. What you're trying to do is find numeric values.

Comment: @omar180791 : You try to represent a "space or tab" by `\s`. AFIK, if you want to use this notation, you need to use the `-P` option, Also you did not include in your question some examples (or a description) of the lines you try to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to test the number against your value, and not test a string against any pattern (as already suggested in comments). For example like this:

```
awk '/^PASS_MAX_DAYS/ && $2<=90' /etc/login.defs
```

This way, you can easily modify your command, if your limit changes to `30` or to `365` days. Also I guess values like `090` are still valid for that configuration.

Answer (score 0):

`grep`, by default, doesn't understand extended regular expressions ..

```
grep -E "^PASS_MAX_DAYS\s*([0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|90)\s*$" /etc/login.defs
```

will give you SOME result.

That said, how many different entries for `PASS_MAX_DAYS` do you expect in that file?